# How to fix syntax error while converting decimal to isnull in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am converting a MS SQL Server stored procedure to a stored function in PostgresSQL. In that need to convert a decimal value to isnull using coalesce, but in that line I am getting a syntax error.

**StoredFunction:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetDeptListForViewModifyJointUsePercentages (
     p_nInstID numeric,
     p_nDeptID numeric) RETURNS VOID
AS  $$  
declare v_AccountTotal decimal(18,2);
BEGIN
select SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2), coalesce(eam.npayroll_amt, 0))) as AccountTotal
        FROM 
            Account acct

            INNER JOIN employeeaccountmapping eam 
                ON eam.nacct_id = acct.naccount_id

                AND acct.ninst_id =p_nInstID
          where acct.ndept_id =p_nDeptID
)
```

**OutputPane:**

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 7: select SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2), coalesce(eam.npayroll_amt,...
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a type cast:

```
CAST (coalesce(...) AS decimal(18,2))
```

Comment: Now select clause is working , but why it is giving error at closing bracket ?

Comment: i got it ,instead of bracket need to complete query using ";".